# Twitter oauth/request_token failing sometimes

Tags: javascript, twitter, air, oauth

I'm implementing Twitters OAuth for Adobe AIR in Javascript. My problem is, that out of 100 requests to api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token about 30 fail with the usual error message: `Failed to validate oauth signature and token`

The other 70% of requests produce a correct response, so I believe that my algorithm for signing is correct.

I've read about invalid timestamps in a lot of forums and mailing lists but that is not the problem. My timestamps are correct.

I also checked, if the nonces are unique, so that's not the cause either.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: There have been disruptions and outages on Twitter over the last few days (more than usually, that is). Are you sure what you are seeing is independant of that?

Comment: Actually, I'm asking me exactly that. I'm not sure wether it's my code or the API thats's failing.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. Sometimes I get a 401, but most of the time it works. For me it seems to only affect specific users.

Comment: In my case it was the timestamp portion of the reqeust. User had their time set back a few hours, so Twitter wouldn't provide a token.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this same behavior in my case: 30% of the time Twitter would return "Failed to validate oauth signature and token".

In my case, I just retry the call immediately and now I have 100% success.  In most cases, when the call fails, the immediate call afterwards is successful.  This seems to fix it for me.